# Javascript converting addEventListener to attachEvent

Tags: javascript, attachevent

I have the following code calling a Javascript function in a nice shiny standards complient manner :). Please note that I must send `elementsList[i]` to the function (the this keyword will not be adaquate) as the event listerner is being attached to it's nephew (for want of a better term)

This rather mangled code will effectively find the control element for the dynamic behaviour of the current node in elementsList[i] and add a click event listener to it. When fired it passes the clicked node to the toggle function.

```
elementsList[i].previousSibling.lastChild.addEventListener
("click", (function(el){return function(){toggle(el)};})(elementsList[i]),false);
```

Thing is it doesn't work at all with IE8 and below, and in spite of spending most of the morning trying to find a work around I just can't get it to play ball. If someone knows how to translate this into IE crapo code, I'd be grateful to see it.

Comment: As I already commented at your previous question, you should read http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
elementsList[i].previousSibling.lastChild.attachEvent
("onclick", (function(el){return function(){toggle(el)};})(elementsList[i]),false);
```

Comment: How did that work?????? I've been trying similiar variations for hours. I'm certain I tried that already!

Comment: attachEvent takes two arguments: event name and function, so "false" is unnecessary

Comment: Does `el` actually refer to the element that was clicked in IE? - trying to find specs on what parameters are expected in the handler.

Comment: e.g. I thought you needed... `function(event){var el = event.srcElement;....` attaching:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536913%28v=VS.85%29.aspx event object:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535863%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

2 potential suggestions.

1.) Include [jQuery](http://www.jQuery.com/) in your project and use their x-browser event bindings (or [mootools](http://mootools.net/) or some other lib)

2.) Not so-recommended, roll your own x-browser event bindings